# Using Spark how to add column at the end

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Below is my dataset using spark I want to add one more column at the end with name Level. Based on the salary the Level will be decided

```
`sal >= 1000 && sal <=2000  = Level 1
sal > 2000 && sal <= 3000  = Level 2 
sal >3000 && sal <=4000 = Level 3

+-----+-------+----+----+
|empid|empName| sal|dept|
+-----+-------+----+----+
|  100|  EMP1 |1000|IT  |
|  101|  EMP2 |2500|ITES|
|  102|  EMP3 |3000|BPO |
|  104|  EMP4 |4000|ENGG|
+-----+-------+----+----+`
```

Output

```
+-----+-------+----+----+-----+
|empid|empName| sal|dept|Level|
+-----+-------+----+----+-----+
|  100|  EMP1 |1000|IT  |Level 1|
|  101|  EMP2 |2500|ITES|Level 2|
|  102|  EMP3 |3000|BPO |Level 3|
|  104|  EMP4 |4000|ENGG|Level 3|
+-----+-------+----+----+-----+
```

I have written below code -

`case class mySchema(empid: Int, empName: String, sal: Int, post: String)
import spark.implicits._
    val rdd1 = spark.read.csv("file:///E:/dev/tools/SampleData/emp.csv").select($"_c0".cast("integer").as("empid"),$"_c1".cast("string").as("empName"),$"_c2".cast("integer").as("sal"),$"_c3".cast("string").as("post"))
    val df1 = rdd1.toDF()
    val dfTods = df1.as[mySchema]
    dfTods.createTempView("Employee")
    val resDS = spark.sql("""select  *

                             case when (sal === 1000) then 'ASE' 
                             when (sal === 2000) then 'SE' 
                             else 'SSE'

                             end as  level from Employee""")`

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
    mismatched input 'when' expecting (line 2, pos 70)

```
== SQL ==
select  *   case when (sal === 1000) then 'ASE' 
----------------------------------------------------------------------^^^
                                                                 when (sal === 2000) then 'SE' 
                                                                 else 'SSE'  
                                                                 end as  level  from Employee
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? How to get to the desired output when you have a table like the one shown above? Where is what you tried so far? Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example <https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve>. For more information, please see How to Ask<https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask> and take the tour<stackoverflow.com/tour>.

Comment: Missing `,` between `*` and `case`.

Comment: @RahulWagh could you unaccept my answer? I want to delete it because it's wrong

Comment: Unaccepted the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
select  
*,  
case   
when (sal >=1000 and sal <= 2000) then 'Level 1'  
when (sal > 2000 and sal <= 3000) then 'Level 2'  
when (sal > 3000 and sal <= 4000) then 'Level 3'
end   
as level  
from Employee
```

Comment: instead of putting all column names in select can't I use * for all columns rather than typing all the columns

Comment: Okay so it means if you want all the columns of the table in the output then you have to put all the column names...the asterisk(*) does not work

Comment: if you want to add a new column to your select clause in addition to already existing columns, then yes, you have to specify all columns and you can't use asterisk

Comment: mangusta thanks for your answer it helps. I had one more question I am trying to do same thing using select but it is not working -   import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._`
val resDF = df1.select($"empid, empName,sal,post",
(when($"sal"  >=  1000 and $"sal" <= 2000,"ASE"))
(when($"sal" === 20000 and $"sal" <= 3000,"SE"))
(when($"sal" > 20000 and $"sal" <= 4000,"SSE")).as("Level"))`

Comment: your code in your question was correct, the only part you need to change is "val resDS = spark.sql(...)". you should pass my query to "sql( )" method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183444/discussion-between-rahul-wagh-and-mangusta).

Comment: @mangusta Saying that you cannot use `*` along with a case/when statement is simply wrong. He simply forgot to put a comma `,` after the `*` !

Comment: @cheseaux ok you're right. it's better if you post the answer and the OP changes the accepted answer to yours, after that I will be able to delete my answer. I neither want a negative reputation on accepted answer nor a wrong answer to be accepted

Comment: @cheseaux let me try by putting ,

Comment: @cheseaux I have modified the query by adding the asterisk. Could you remove your downvote? if not, i will have to remove my answer because it could be misleading for others